# Multiple open statements with multiple tables causes 'SQL logic error' in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I create multiple tables (at least two):

```
CREATE TABLE prices0
(
  dt NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  buy REAL NOT NULL,
  sell REAL NOT NULL
) WITHOUT ROWID;

CREATE TABLE prices1
(
  dt NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  buy REAL NOT NULL,
  sell REAL NOT NULL
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

and insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO prices0 (dt, buy, sell) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
INSERT INTO prices0 (dt, buy, sell) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

In my C++ code I open and execute the statements as follows:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    sqlite3_prepare(...);
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    sqlite3_bind_int64(...);
    sqlite3_bind_double(...);
    sqlite3_bind_double(...);
    
    sqlite3_step(...);
    sqlite3_reset(...);
}
```

The first call of `sqlite3_step` function fails with error code '1' and the message 'SQL logic error'.

The same code does not produce any errors with the single table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because when I create the second table the database schema is changed, see

```
p->zErrMsg = sqlite3DbStrDup(db, "database schema has changed");
```

in SQLite sources.